# Count and display size of incoming stdin (count lines)

Tags: unix, logging, command-line-tool

Is there a program that would result in output like "wc -l" but that would update counter on more data.

Here is what I want it for:

```
tail -f log/production.log | grep POST | wc -l
```

But wc -l should be changed for something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
tail -f log/production.log | grep --line-buffered POST | awk '{printf "\r%d", ++i} END {print ""}'
```

This prints the line count after every line of input. The carriage return `\r` makes each line number overwrite the last, so you only see the most recent one.

Use `grep --line-buffered` to make grep flush its output after each line rather than every 4KB. Or you can combine the `grep` and `awk` into one:

```
tail -f log/production.log | awk '/POST/ {printf "\r%d", ++i} END {print ""}'
```

Comment: hm, it updates number slowly. I would want it to update live and to be in one line